# Jquery Traversal In Nested Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to get the input text value of the below code. I am new to jquery but I tried to get the value using find medthod but it did not work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="search_div_main">
      <form type="submit" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="Search" id="search_form_id">
        <div id="search_div" class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="search_input" style="width:500px" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Value....">
        </div>
      </form>
      ...
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

I need to get the text value of the input box(id="search_input").

Comment: You do not need to traverse, you could simply get the value by `$('#search_input').val();`

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("search_input").value
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#search_input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#search_input").val()` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var search_input = $("#search_input").val();
    window.alert(search_input);

})
```

A couple of things you should learn if you are new to jQuery:

- Always wrap your code inside `.ready()` Like `jQuery( document ).ready(function($){ /*CODE*/ });`
- `$` is an alias to the `jQuery` function, in some case it's not available.